# Failed to load ApplicationContext only from integration tests

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

ON spring boot 2.1.8.RELEASE application when it is started from Integration test

I use JPA, gradle dep:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

My test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test") // application.properteis is the same as for local profile.
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "logging.file=build/logs/unittest.log")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

(have some dummy empty test there that does not test anything. The point is just to start app from the test. and check if context is up.)

I got:

> Failed to load ApplicationContext java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Failed to load ApplicationContext

It fails somewhere on validation, but locally not exception about some inconsistencies in the JPA entities and relationships about them:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key..blah blah

**BUT when I start app normally I do not have that exception.**

I believe integration tests tries to do too much, doing all that validation over all entities?

Q: **How to avoid it, I just need it start as it starts when run application normally?** (even if there is jpa mapping problem I do not want them to prevent context to fail to behave same way when run normally)

**again**: the application-test/local.properties for local (normal) profile and the test one a **completely identical**. same data base

**Stack trace:** (put it here temporally - do not believe is important)

> Failed to load ApplicationContext java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Failed to load ApplicationContext     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:352)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:204)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassTestDescriptor.java:352)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:351)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
>     at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)    at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:98)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:97)
>     at
>   org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)   at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
>     at
>   org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FKssmt1homue4qrva4i8wh9i0c2:mymodel_language_title [mymodel_uuid]))
>   must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key
>   (mymodel_language_title [mymodel_uuid,language_id])   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>     ... 87 more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FKssmt1homue4qrva4i8wh9i0c2:mymodel_language_title [mymodel_uuid]))
>   must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key
>   (mymodel_language_title [mymodel_uuid,language_id])   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:148)    at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:130)    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1933)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1849)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1668)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
>     at org.springframework.orm

Comment: It's nearly impossible to figure this one out without more details; can you paste the whole stacktrace and possibly Spring Boot config that you use for the different profiles?

Comment: just mock the JPA repository if you don't need it

Comment: was looking for some flag maybe to turn one validation on test run. as I do not have any when start application. @x80486 the stack trace is not important: the relationship between table is wrong. I can fix it. but I just want test behave as local (will attach stack-trace anyhow)